# SAS http and oauth

Tags: oauth, sas, token

I am new in SAS and i am not sure if there is any function or package in order to get a token and authorization using SAS.

I would like using the proc http, to obtain a token and after use this toke to connect to the web. Any ideas?

Something like:

```
proc http
url="the name of the web"
method="POST"
IDCLIENT="MY ID CLIENT"
IDPASSWORD="MY ID PASSWORD"

run;
```

So i could obtain a token, which I will use to connect to the web.

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings17/SAS0224-2017.pdf)?

Comment: are you talking about SAS Skandinavian Airlines Systems?? or SAS: Analytics, Business Intelligence and Data Management

Comment: are you sure they support oAuth?

Comment: Yes, I have seen three place in which they use it, but I cant not recieved any token and I would like to know if someone have used before and she/he could help me. I am talking about SAS: Analytics, Business Intelligence and Data Management , thank you :)

Comment: where are the 3 places that you saw? is there any ref in the web?